# Cannot install the gem pg -v '0.15.1'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have tried installing the packet libpq-dev, and installing postgresql, but bundle install still fails due to gem pg. This is the error I get:

```
$ gem install pg -v '0.15.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-
p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:73: warning: Insecure 
world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again 
with --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config

checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

What is a proper way to clean up the mess?

Comment: What OS are you running?  How did you install postgres?

Comment: Mac OS Mavericks, and I installed it by the 'postgresql-9.3.2-3-osx' file, but I'm still not sure where it went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Mac, install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and then install Postgres using the command

brew install postgresql

Or you can download and install Postgres from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/download/) depending on which OS you are using.

Comment: Homebrew is definitely the simplest way to install Postgres on a Mac.(Postgres for Dummies)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any "mess" - it's a standard issue where your system does not have the required libraries to install the gem

---

**Library**

As mentioned in the comments, you first need to [install PGSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/installation.html), which will create the required library files to help the gem install, after that you can use some path references to help the gem install:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-dir="C:/Program Files/installer
```